# Wordpress: nav_menu_link_attributes won't accept variable as attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to take a custom color that was chosen by the user in the Customizer, and add it as an html attribute to the links that are outputted by a specific menu.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Gets the footer link color, if assigned by user.
if (get_theme_mod('theme_footer_link_color')) {
    $footerLinkColorAttribute = 'color:' . get_theme_mod('theme_footer_link_color', 'default_value') . ';';
}

function add_customizer_link_color_attribute_to_footer_menu_links($atts, $item, $args){
    if ($args->theme_location == 'footerNavLocation') {
      $atts['style'] = $footerLinkColorAttribute;
    }
return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_customizer_link_color_attribute_to_footer_menu_links', 10, 3);
```

My problem is that the style attribute is taking $footerLinkColorAttribute as plain text, instead of a variable that contains the text set by the user.

How can I get it to be taken as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was defining the variable outside of the function, but needed to define it inside of the function:

```
function add_customizer_link_color_attribute_to_footer_menu_links($atts, $item, $args){
    if ($args->theme_location == 'footerNavLocation') {
        // If there is a footer link color assigned in the Customizer, this gets it ready to be inserted as an attribute into the link menu link text.
        if (get_theme_mod('lets_get_started_footer_link_color')) {
            $footerLinkColorAttribute = 'color:' . get_theme_mod('lets_get_started_footer_link_color', 'default_value') . ';';
        }
      $atts['style'] = $footerLinkColorAttribute;
    }
return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_customizer_link_color_attribute_to_footer_menu_links', 10, 3);
```